# Get data by pages and merge it into one using Python (pagination)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm connecting to API which has 500 rows limit per call.

This is my code for a single API call (Works great):

```
def getdata(data):
    auth_token = access_token
    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    urlApi = 'https://..../orders?Offset=0&Limit=499'
    datar = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=True)
    return datar
```

Now I want to scale it up so it will get me all the records.

This is what I tried to do:

In order to make sure that I have all the rows, I must iterate until there is no more data:

```
get 1st page
get 2nd page
merge
get 3rd page
merge
etc...
```

each page is an API call.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def getData(data):
    auth_token = access_token
    value_offset = 0
    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    datarALL = None
    while True:
        urlApi = 'https://..../orders?Offset=' + value_offset + '&Limit=499'
        responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=True)
        if responsedata.ok:
            value_offset = value_offset + 499

            #to do: merge the result of the get request 
            datarALL= datarALL+ responsedata  (?)
            # to do: check if response is empty then break out.

    return datarALL
```

I couldn't find information about how I merge the results of the API calls nor how do I check if I can break the loop.

**Edit:**
To clear what I'm after.
I can see the results of the API call using:

```
logger.debug('response is : {0}'.format(datar.json()))
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
logger.debug('response is : {0}'.format(datarALL.json()))
```

and it will show all results from all calls. This requires generate API calls until there is no more data to get.

This is the return sample of API call:

```
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 0,
  "total": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "field1": 0,
      "field2": "string",
      "field3": "string",
      "field4": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: depends on the structure of response returned from the api. please share it

Comment: @ShanavasM see edit

Comment: The problem is -- a magic method does not exist. You need to know the data structure returned and merge it by yourselves. Besides, if you want to know the end, you need to know what will be the API return when there is no more data.

Comment: @MatrixTai added sample. The question is if after the change I will still have datar  object (request,get() ) or I must change it? Currently I'm using only "results" and ignore other fields as they are metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are almost correct with the idea.

```
is_valid = True
while is_valid:
    is_valid = False
    ...
    ...
    responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=True)
    if responsedata.status_code == 200: #Use status code to check request status, 200 for successful call
        responsedata = responsedata.text
        value_offset = value_offset + 499

        #to do: merge the result of the get request
        jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
        if "results" in jsondata:
            if jsondata["results"]:
                is_valid = True
        if is_valid:
            #concat array by + operand
            datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]
```

As I don't know if `"results"` still exists when the data ran out, so I checked both level.

Comment: @Programmer120 , is this what you want?

Comment: It fails on: `jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)`  this is the error       `jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: @Programmer120 , it means your API is not returning you a json string. Print it out and also print the `type(responsedata)`. Take a look, a json string means it should be a string, but with structure, for example `"{response:[{field:'sample'}]}"`

Comment: `type(responsedata)` gives: `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`

Comment: @Programmer120, see edited, I forget to add a line for getting text.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datarALL' referenced before assignment`  I assume we need `datarALL = [ ]` ?

Comment: I think the condition `if jsondata["results"]:` is incorrect. The results key will always appear even if it is empty. I need to check that it has data or use the `total` field which contains the total number of records. total / limit should give the numbers of loop run required. How can I access them?

Comment: @Programmer120, First question, for sure, I just provide the key part code for you. I dun even know what API you are using, how can I test it.  Second question, in python `if []` is `false`, so if the result is empty, it won't continue. But in case you still want the total, use `result["total"]`, json object is just `dictionary`.

Comment: For this code (141 total recods and limit of 100 per call) :             `if is_valid:
                # concat array by + operand
                print "im valid"
                datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]
                print datarALL`   it should print only if there is actual data in results. but I also see this print `{"offset":200,"limit":100,"total":141,"results":[]}`   I had 3 runs of the loop while It should have been 2 runs for this data. The end condition is incorrect...

Comment: @Programmer120 , it should run 3 times and stop at 4th times. Okay, consider the code step by step. At the 2nd run, there should be 100~200 data comes out. **Thus**, `is_valid` is still true, there is result. And then go to 3rd run, this time no result returns. **Thus**, `is_valid` is false, and thus it dun go for 4th run.

Comment: **It is ok for you to use result["total"]** for determination, not hard, you can try by urself.

Comment: OK got it. It seems to work. The only issue I'm having is since the code is using `responsedata = responsedata.text`  it changes the structure of the return which is a problem for me. Is there a way to return the same type as the original code?

Comment: @Programmer120 , that's why `json.loads(responsedata)` is added. You may try `responsedata.json()`, is just same as `json.loads(responsedata)`

Comment: Lets assume this code is in function called `func()` which returns `datarALL` . so I'm doing `x = func() `  Now, I want to check that I have results so I do: if `x.ok: logger.debug(' response is : {0}'.format(x.json()))`   - It fails over    ` if x.ok:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ok'`   - It doesn't fail if I run it over the original code ( without the paging) meaning that the returned object is not the same...

Comment: @Programmer120 , you already figure out the error right? ` 'list' object has no attribute 'ok'`, list doesn't have any object called `ok`.  Seems like you are new for python... you need to read some tutorial about `list` and `dictionary` first. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm

Comment: I know what the error means. What I don't understand is how to convert this to the same object as the original. I'm relying the the returned object will be the same requests.get() return (from the original function).  I want to localize the change only to this function and not return different object which will require further code modifications.

Comment: @Programmer120 , what you want to do is pretty strange.  "offset", "limit", "total" , how do you want to summarize these three field when combining them? Simply `datarALL.append(jsondata)` is not what you want right?

Comment: @Programmer120 If that's the case just use a constant to save it, like `limit = jsondata["limit"]`. And then at the last, create a dictionary urself, put them inside by `mydatadict["result"] = datarALL`. Thats it. No magic method.

Comment: Check my followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692872/how-to-convert-response-from-request-get-to-dataframe