# how to convert response from request.get to DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out 

def importdata(data):
    responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    return responsedata


def generatejson(response):
    # Generate flat json file
    sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response.json())['results'].to_dict()
    flat = {k: flat_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
    return json.dumps(flat, sort_keys=True)

response = importdata(data)
flat_json = generatejson(response)
```

Sample of what `importdata(data)` returns:
https://textuploader.com/dz30p

This code send get request to API get the result parse them and generate a JSON file.

This works great.

Now, I want to modify the `importdata` function to support pagination (Multiple calls that are merged together).

So I wrote this code:

```
def impordatatnew():
...
is_valid = True
value_offset = 0
value_limit = 100
datarALL = []
while is_valid:
        is_valid = False
        urlApi = 'http://....?offset={1}&limit={2}&startDate={0}'.format(
            requestedDate,value_offset,value_limit)
        responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
        if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # Use status code to check request status, 200 for successful call
            responsedata = responsedata.text   
            value_offset = value_offset + value_limit
            # to do: merge the result of the get request
            jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
            if "results" in jsondata:
                if jsondata["results"]:
                    is_valid = True
            if is_valid:
                # concat array by + operand
                datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]
        else:
            #TODO handle other codes
            print responsedata.status_code
return datarALL
```

This code using pagination. It connects to API gets results page by page and combine them together into a list.  If I do:

`print json.dumps(datarALL)`
I see the combined JSON so this works great.
Example for the dump:
https://jsonblob.com/707ead1c-9891-11e8-b651-496f6b276e89

Sample for `return datarALL`:

https://textuploader.com/dz39d

**My Problem:**

I can't seems to make the return value of `impordatatnew()` to work with `generatejson()`. How can I make the return value of `impordatatnew()` compatible with 
`generatejson()` ? I tried to modify as follows:

```
def generatejsonnew(response):
    #Generate flat json file
    sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response.json()).to_dict()
    flat = {k: flat_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
    return json.dumps(flat, sort_keys=True)
```

It gives:

> sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response.json()).to_dict() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'json'
>   I understand that but I don't know how to solve this. I can't seems to make this conversion works.

Comment: Consider giving a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to play with.

Comment: @mxmt added samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you do this:

```
responsedata = responsedata.text   
jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]
```

It seems like what you're doing here is to incrementally build a list.  You could simplify it to:

```
dataALL += responsedata.json()
```

The problem comes later:

```
pd.DataFrame(response.json())
```

This is because you are calling `json()` again on something which has already been parsed from JSON to a Python list.  Hence the error message.

But the real head-scratcher is why you're doing this:

```
sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response.json()).to_dict()
```

Which isn't really "using Pandas" other than to reformulate a list into a dict.  Surely there is a more direct way of doing that, such as using a `for` loop to build the dict (exactly how, we can't tell without sample data).

Anyway, if you want to populate a DataFrame, simply remove the `.json()` part and it should work similarly to your original non-paginating code.

But the far more efficient way to simply construct a DataFrame per page using your original code, and then call `pd.concat(pages)` where `pages` is the list of those DataFrames.  No need to build `dataALL` then.

Ultimately your code can be simplified so much more, to end up like this:

```
pd.concat(pd.read_json(url, ...) for url in all_page_urls)
```

That is, first you use a `for` loop to build `all_page_urls`, then you use the above one-liner to collect all the data into a single DataFrame.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json

Comment: When I do `sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response).to_dict()`  I get error     `flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`   I don't mind combine the functions and change whatever is needed but It seems like everything I do raise another problem.

Comment: Data samples added to the question

Comment: In your code you look for a key `'results'` but your sample data contains none such.

Comment: datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]  Gives only the results part of what I get from the API call.. This is the only thing that interests me.  In the original code (before the change) the importdata data just get the data without manipulate it so inside the generatejson I consider only ["results"]

Comment: this is a sample data of the importdata call (original function):  https://textuploader.com/dz30p      It has total,limit,results,offset   The actual data I want to get is in the results part. The rest is just metadata which I don't care about.

Comment: Also, I can't use your suggested approach of  `all_page_urls` because I don't know how many pages I'm going to have. I'm looping as long as `jsondata["results"]` is not empty.

Comment: I tried anything I could think of redarding : `sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response.json()).to_dict()`    , also tried: `sample_object = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(response)).to_dict()`   Nothing works.  What I'm trying to do now is to change the return type of `def impordatatnew()` to return exactly the same object as `importdata()` but I can't seem to understand what `requests.get()` returns.... If I can return the exact same object everything should work. The function `generatejsonnew(response)` won't be needed if I can return the same object...

Comment: Stop calling requests.get() and pd.DataFrame.  `pd.read_json()` can do it all in one call.

Comment: But how I integrate it? I have `data=data, headers=hed, verify=False` Which are:  `hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}   data = {"client_id": "....", "client_secret": "...",
            "grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "PublicApi"} ` I'm creating authorization for the API call. I don't see the suggested function having support for it.